# Identity over the reals

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

In the course of proving that a quadratic has two real roots, it would be very helpful to use the inequality $x^2+y^2>2xy$.

Is this inequality true for every set of two positive real numbers?

Comment: Why are you stipulating that $x,y$ must be positive?  Could it not be true if one or both were negative?  Wouldn't it be even more helpful if we could show it for *more* reals.  I mean if we are going to dream, let's dream big.

Comment: Well, I'm doing a problem for a mathematical modeling course, and all the constants are stipulated to be positive by the constraints of the problem. As a mathematician I agree, but as a biologist it doesn't bother me either way :)

Comment: I was being slightly facetious, but it turns out that it is true whether the numbers are positive or negative.  After all $x^2 + y^2 \ge 0$ and $2|x||y| \ge 2xy=\pm 2|x||y|$ so ... it wouldn't matter.  It'd be true or not true either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is false whenever $x=y$, clearly.

If $x\neq y$ then:  $$(x-y)^2>0\implies x^2-2xy +y^2>0\implies x^2+y^2>2xy$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
x^2+y^2>2xy\iff (x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy>0 
$$
which is true for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The inequality does not hold for $x=0,y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + y^2 >2xy \iff$

$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 > 0 \iff$

$(x-y)^2 > 0 \iff$ (assuming $x,y \in \mathbb R$)

$x-y \ne 0 \iff$

$x \ne y$.

And if $x = y$ then $x^2 + y^2 = 2x^2 = 2xy$.

So $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2xy$ for any pair of real numbers with equality holding if and only if $x = y$.